# Problemas al filtrar datos en Primevue vue 3

Tags: vue.js, primefaces, vue3

Estoy siguiendo la documentacion de filtrar datos con PrimeVue en vue 3 , al momento de ejecutar el filtro no me muestra ningun resultado.

Este es el codigo de la tabla.

```
  <DataTable ref="dt" 
            v-model:selection="selectListdocdia" 
            :value="listactrldoc" dataKey="IDCTROLCAJA"
            :paginator="true" 
            :rows="10" 
            :filters="filters" 
            class="p-datatable-gridlines"
            paginatorTemplate="FirstPageLink PrevPageLink PageLinks NextPageLink LastPageLink CurrentPageReport RowsPerPageDropdown"
            :rowsPerPageOptions="[5, 10, 25]"
            currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {first} to {last} of {totalRecords} listactrldoc"
            responsiveLayout="scroll"
                >
                <template #header>
                    <div class="flex flex-column md:flex-row md:justify-content-between md:align-items-center">
                        <h5 class="m-0">Lista de Documentos </h5>
                        <span class="block mt-2 md:mt-0 p-input-icon-left">
                            <i class="pi pi-search" />
                            <InputText v-model="filters['global'].value" placeholder="Buscar" style="width: 100%" />
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </template>
</Datatable>
```

**Luego tengo mi siguiente metodo.**

```
   methods: {
    initFilters1() {
        this.filters = {
            global: { value: null, matchMode: FilterMatchMode.CONTAINS },
            Cliente: { operator: FilterOperator.AND, constraints: [{ value: null, matchMode: FilterMatchMode.STARTS_WITH }] },
        };
    },
```

}

**este metodo lo invoco en el siguiente ciclo de vida.**

```
   created() {
    this.initFilters1()
},
```

Antes de realizar la búsqueda se muestra la información cargada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego al realizar la búsqueda no se muestra nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo que esta faltando , estoy siguiendo la documentación de este enlace, la información lo obtengo desde mi api.

Si tuvieran alguna idea de lo que estaría fallando , me serviría de gran ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Por fin pude encontrar la solucion, agregando la siguiente linea en el componente del datatable.

```
:globalFilterFields="['IDCTROLCAJA', 'CLIENTE' , 'DESC_BANCO']"
```

lo que hace es indicarle las columnas que se va filtrar de manera global.